# Prevent side by side textblock from overlapping

Tags: layout, grid, textblock, windows-store-apps, overlapping

I am trying to develop a windows store app and I am having an issue. Keep in mind that I am a newbie.

In the header part, I am trying to have my title on the left and a small text on the right (on the same line). I placed a two column grid and placed a textblock in each column. The result here is that the two textblock overlaps, which is not what I want. Here is the code:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="600*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource txtHeaders}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Text on the right" Style="{StaticResource txtHeaders}" />
</Grid>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Also, the style txtHeaders define only the text color, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the second textblock is being placed in the same column as the first one. To shift it to the second one, use grid.column = "1". Therefore, the second textblock will be as follows: